# Boost Threads - Producer Consumer threads with synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization, producer-consumer

Please review this for concurrency  correctness:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

#include "boost\thread.hpp"
#include "boost\timer.hpp"

std::queue<int> itemQ;

boost::mutex m;
boost::condition_variable qFull, qEmpty;

const int max_size_q = 5;


void producer()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(1000));
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);      
        if (itemQ.size() <= max_size_q)
        {
            itemQ.push(++i);
            qEmpty.notify_one();
        }   
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "Q Full.notify_one Producer Waiting" << std::endl;
            qFull.wait(lock);
            std::cout << "Producer Notified to Continue" << std::endl;
        }
    }

}

void consumer()
{
    while (1)
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(4000));

        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);

        if (itemQ.size() == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Q Empty. Consumer " << boost::this_thread::get_id() <<" Waiting" << std::endl;
            qEmpty.wait(lock);
            std::cout << "Consumer Notified to Continue" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << itemQ.front() << std::endl;
            itemQ.pop();
            qFull.notify_one();
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread producerthread(producer);

    boost::thread consumerthread1(consumer);
    boost::thread consumerthread2(consumer);
    boost::thread consumerthread3(consumer);
    boost::thread consumerthread4(consumer);
    boost::thread consumerthread5(consumer);

    consumerthread1.join();
    consumerthread2.join();
    consumerthread3.join();
    consumerthread4.join();
    consumerthread5.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the condition variable will probably work but is a-typical.

This is what you basically have:

```
while (1)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);      
    if (<Test OK>)
    {
        <Do Work>
        <Notify Consumer>
    }   
    else 
    {
        <Wait for consumer to signal conditional>
    }
}
```

Notice that here you lock the mutex `m`. If the test is **not** OK then you wait for the consumer to signal the condition variable. This releases the lock on `m`. Once the condition variable is signaled then your thread must wait to re-aquire the lock to continue. Once it does it releases the lock and then re-starts the loop which immediately try to re-aquire the lock.

A more typical pattern would be:

```
// pseudo code.
std::unique_ptr<WORK> getWork()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);      
    while(! <Test OK> )
    {
       <Wait for consumer to signal conditional>
    }
    return <getWorkObjectFromQueue>; 
}
.....
while(1)
{
    work = getWork();

    <Do Work>
    <Notify Consumer>
}
```

This way when you are waiting on the conditional variable and are signaled you do not have multiple attempts to re-acquire the lock before you do the work. As soon as you are signaled and have acquired the lock you can do a bit of work.

Comment: In your case the scopes make the two operations serial, which is often not desired. For example I might want to queue up 1000 work units.

Comment: @Mikhail: You are correct. I was just trying to impart the pattern. But I have updated to make it more obvious.